# Maximum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider $$f^+ =\max\{f,0\}, f:X \rightarrow  \mathbb{R} $$

Assume $(f+g)^+ \ne \infty $.

How can I conclude $f^+ +g^+ \ne \infty $

Comment: The statement is false as written, consider $X=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=-x$.

Comment: Ok then the proof I found is wrong. The other way around would work?

Comment: Yes, I believe the converse is correct. You can prove it by saying if $f^++g^+$ is finite, then both $f$ and $g$ must be bounded above, in which case $f+g$ must also be bounded above.